# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. What could be wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SaleNew(ENQ_AID,DOCKET_NO,SALE_TYPE,VEHICLE_MODEL,SALE_DATE,BOOKING_DATE,DELIVERY_DATE,
                    DEALER_NAME,ENQ_GEN_BY,EXEC_NAME,USER_CR,DATE_CR) SELECT '6','2','0','TEST','2016-05-01','2016-05-10','2016-05-15',
   'ABC','S I','V B','1',SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

What could be wrong with this query?

Also tried:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SaleNew(ENQ_AID,DOCKET_NO,SALE_TYPE,VEHICLE_MODEL,SALE_DATE,BOOKING_DATE,DELIVERY_DATE,
                    DEALER_NAME,ENQ_GEN_BY,EXEC_NAME,USER_CR,DATE_CR) SELECT '6','2','0','TEST',CONVERT(DATE,'01/05/2016',103),CONVERT(DATE,'10/05/2016',103),
   CONVERT(DATE,'15/05/2016',103),'ABC','S I','V B','1',SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30')
```

This is the create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SaleNew](
[SALE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ENQ_AID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[DOCKET_NO] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[VEHICLE_MODEL] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[SALE_DATE] [date] NULL,
[BOOKING_DATE] [date] NULL,
[DELIVERY_DATE] [date] NULL,
[DEALER_NAME] [date] NULL,
[ENQ_GEN_BY] [varchar](100) NULL,
[EXEC_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
[USER_CR] [int] NULL,
[DATE_CR] [date] NULL,
[USER_UP] [int] NULL,
[DATE_UP] [date] NULL,
[SALE_TYPE] [int] NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_SaleNew] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[SALE_ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Could you send us `SaleNew` table definition?

Comment: Absolutely no point to anyone speculating without the schema of the destination table. Providing this and the `insert` query, both with line breaks showing the actual correspondence between columns, would help a lot.

Comment: `[DEALER_NAME] [date] NULL` ?? This is a reason

Comment: date_cr has type DATE but you store a datetime. And gofr is right! DEALER_NAME must be varchar!

Comment: thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEALER_NAME` type is defined as `DATE` but you want to `INSERT` a `VARCHAR` type value `ABC` in it.

Execute following query in order to edit the mentioned column type, then Execute your `INSERT` query.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SaleNew]
ALTER COLUMN [DEALER_NAME] VARCHAR(50) NULL
```